# Conflict between Tufte and gb4e in title \thanks

Tags: margins, tufte, gb4e

I use Tufte-book class and only add gb4e package as

```
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
```

But after adding this, the thanks part in title does not go to the margin. 
Full code is as below:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}

\usepackage{marginfix} % floats sidenots
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\title{This is title
        \thanks{thanks}}

\author[author]{author}
\date{April, 2020}  


\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{units}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}

\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}

\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}
\newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quote}\noindent}{\end{quote}} 

\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\noindent Abstract

\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

And it looks like this now:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Could you please make your code compilable (and remove any packages that aren't needed to show the problem). Your posted code (even adding `\documentclass{tufte-book}` ) produces lots of errors unrelated to the problem you are describing.